# Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError 206 iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I realise there are many questions for this but none specific to my problem. I am using the iOS SDK for Parse, v1.8.5 (latest).
Every time I try to `saveInBackground...` on `PFUser.currentUser()` I get this error occurring and when I pause the program and check `po PFUser.currentUser()` in the console it displays the current user fine and logged in with no problems. I do not understand why I am getting this problem then..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means you try to change an user without have the right to do that. Check if you're applying changes to your current user and that you're properly logged in (I would also check that I'm not anonymous but not very sure if this can cause a problem).

Comment: Have you queried for any other user or something like that?